# How do I merge two mpl maps producing a new map?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

However I tweek the following code, there seems to be a point I am missing. It will not compile. I have two maps int -> int. I want to produce a third int -> int map containing all the key-value pairs from the two originals. (VS2013) Anyone?

```
#include <boost/mpl/map.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pair.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/has_key.hpp>

typedef boost::mpl::map <
    boost::mpl::pair < boost::mpl::int_<7>, boost::mpl::int_<59>  >
>::type Original1;

typedef boost::mpl::map <
    boost::mpl::pair < boost::mpl::int_<11>, boost::mpl::int_<61>  >
>::type Original2;

typedef boost::mpl::copy <
    Original1,
    boost::mpl::back_inserter < Original2 >
>::type Merged;

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((boost::mpl::has_key<Merged, 7>));

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    const int i = boost::mpl::at<Merged, boost::mpl::int_<7> >::type::value;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. The simple one is here:

```
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((boost::mpl::has_key<Merged, 7>));
```

Keys are types, `7` is not a type. You want to check for the key `mpl::int_<7>`.

The second is here:

```
typedef boost::mpl::copy <
    Original1,
    boost::mpl::back_inserter < Original2 > // <==
>::type Merged;
```

`mpl::back_inserter` is the metaprogramming equivalent of [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), which creates an OutputIterator which outputs via `push_back()`. Similarly, [`back_inserter`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/back-inserter.html) requires a "Back Extensible Sequence" because it  uses `mpl::push_back`. `mpl::map` isn't a Back Extensible Sequence. If you look at its [reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/map.html), there's no `push_back`, only `insert`. So you need to do that:

```
using Merged =
    mpl::copy<
        Original1,
        mpl::inserter<Original2, mpl::insert<mpl::_1, mpl::_2>> // <==
    >::type;
```

---

I don't quite understand what `mpl::quote` is doing, but it seems broken (er, actually, `mpl::insert` takes 3 arguments and `mpl::quote3` doesn't allow for defaulting the last arguments). If you write:

```
template <template <class... > class F>
struct quote {
    template <class... Args>
    struct apply {
        using type = typename F<Args...>::type;
    };
};
```

then you could have just written:

```
mpl::inserter<Original2, quote<mpl::insert>>
```

Comment: @ØyvindRoth No worries. Welcome to SO. Please see [what should I do when someone answers?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)